# Pull data from asp.net web page using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am new to SSIS. My requirement is to pull data from EXCEL spreadsheet which is in asp.net web page. I will have to pull data from that page every day. How can I achieve this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) You need to do/post your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages.

Comment: Try this link http://bit.ly/10OTzOd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decompose your problem into smaller chunks until you have something you can solve. Once you've solved all the smaller problems, you then need to integrate those pieces together to make a cohesive solution.

Reading your problem statement, I see you have the following needs

- extract data from an Excel data source (note, your problem does not specify *what* you should do with it)
- acquire an Excel spreadsheet from a web page
- use SSIS to manage this

### Extract data

Define an [Excel Connection Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139836.aspx) and configure it to work with your file. I hope for your sake that the format of the file is consistent as the Data Flow task will balk if there are changes to the inferred data types.

Add a data flow task to your Control flow and as your source, use an Excel Data Source and set the Connection Manager as the Excel CM you just created. Select the appropriate destination and wire it up. Do note that string data out of Excel is nvarchar/unicode so you will need to use a data conversion task to switch it to non-unicode type.

### Download a file

Given the paucity of details, I'm left to guess at your needs. Therefore, I guess the Excel file is a link on a web page. The web page is public so no login is required. I further assume that the file on the website is always going to be named the same thing, thus http://contoso.com/Yogurt.xls If the file name changes, http://contoso.com/Yogurt_2013-05-19.xls , http://contoso.com/Yogurt_2013-05-20.xls etc then you have a sub problem of parsing the HTML to find the appropriate link.

With all of those caveats in place, I present [WebClient.DownloadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile.aspx)

```
string url = @"http://contoso.com/Yogurt.xls";
string downloadFile = @"C:\ssisdata\yogurt.xls";
WebClient wc = new WebClient();

wc.DownloadFile(url, downloadFile);
```

As it is hard coded for locations, doesn't perform error handling, etc, this code is not ready for primetime but it demonstrates the solution.

### Use SSIS

The above code would be placed inside a `Script Task` I would pass in the url and download file as Variables to the task so that I have a generic file grabbing task.

Comment: Thank you so much. It solved my issue. Sorry for not able to provide much details. I will improve my skills from next time in asking a question. I appreciate your help.